# How to open phone default SMS inbox using cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I have created application in phonegap, i need to open default SMS inbox on click on inbox icon as i am just showing counter for unread SMS. I need to open phone default inbox on click on that notification icon. I have tried many code and found that i can easily opencomposer and sent box but not inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution to open phone SMS inbox :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList");
```

working for me.

Comment: Working for Micromax A210 But not working in other phone (Like Samsung), Don't know what's happaning. and also working fine in AVD